# How do I run svn resolve in Subversive under Eclipse?

Tags: svn, conflict, subversive, resolve

Firstly: I am using the Subversive plugin in Eclipse to check changes into a long-standing repo containing an Android project.

I've been having a hilarious experience trying to deal with merging the edited trunk of a source tree into one of the branches; I have finally managed to check in most of the new source to the merged branch, mainly by a combination of wrangling and cheating.  I am now trying to finish up and I get this error:

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: 'C:\Users\PCW\workspace\NewsRack Dev Branch\res\drawable' remains in conflict
```

However, if I run Team>Synchronize on the project it says there are no conflicts to resolve.  I have found out elsewhere that running `svn resolve` may be the way to deal with this situation, but Subversive doesn't have any options that obviously correspond to this, and the documentation doesn't clearly tell me how to do it either.

So, broadly, I need a way to tell svn that these conflicts have been resolved from Subversive under Eclipse.

Comment: Please, remove android tag, it's of no use here.

Comment: Is there a menu entry to `Edit conflicts`? I have found some [documentation about that here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/SVNaction/update.php) (last sentence)

Comment: Yes, but clicking it did exactly nothing.  Should have mentioned that, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the following?

Right click in the project in Package Explorer -> Team -> Synchronize with repository.

This will open the Synchronize view. Once you're there, you'll see the files with changes in the left pane; select them and right click over them, then click on "Override and commit". This will upload the changes to the SVN server.